I can't get LiveCharts chart to start at a value other than 0
This is how I create my graph:
private SeriesCollection _graphData;
public SeriesCollection GraphData
{
    get => _graphData;
    set
    {
        _graphData = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

// some other codes as you can imagine


public void UpdateGraphData()
{
    if (Storage.media != null && Storage.media.StreamList.Count > 0 && Storage.media.StreamList[0].FrameList.Count > 0)
    {
        GraphData.Clear();

        if (IsRedSelected)
        {
            GraphData.Add(new LineSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(RedValues),
                Title = "Red Graph",
                Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red
            });
        }
        else if (IsGreenSelected)
        {
            GraphData.Add(new LineSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(GreenValues),
                Title = "Green Graph",
                Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Green
            });
        }
        else if (IsBlueSelected)
        {
            GraphData.Add(new LineSeries
            {
                Values = new ChartValues<double>(BlueValues),
                Title = "Blue Graph",
                Stroke = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Blue
            });
        }

        isGraphCreated = true;
        ShowFrame();
    }
}

And it works great. It shows the list right:
the graph
But as you can see the x axis starts from 0. I want to make it start from another variable. Let's say I have a graph with 10 points and I have a minX value and I want same graph to start from minX and continue to minX+10 value.
This is the xaml code if you need:
<lvc:CartesianChart Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"
            Series="{Binding GraphData}" 
            DisableAnimations="True" 
            Zoom="X" 
            Pan="X"
            DataClick="CartesianChart_OnDataClick">
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
        <lvc:Axis Title="Frame" LabelFormatter="{Binding XAxisLabelFormatter}">
            <lvc:Axis.Sections>
                <lvc:AxisSection Value="{Binding CurrentFramePosition}" StrokeThickness="2" Stroke="Yellow"/>
            </lvc:Axis.Sections>
        </lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
        <lvc:Axis Title="RMS Contrast" LabelFormatter="{Binding YAxisLabelFormatter}" />
    </lvc:CartesianChart.AxisY>
</lvc:CartesianChart>


Have you tried setting the Binding in XAML?
Something along like this
<lvc:Axis Title="Frame" LabelFormatter="{Binding XAxisLabelFormatter}" MinValue="{Binding MinX}" MaxValue="{Binding MaxX}">


The only difference is, the graph screen is shown from minX value (11):
https://imgur.com/a/yokJ6oB
but when i drag the graph, it still starts from 0:
https://imgur.com/a/CoVueUM
